# Spring JMS with IBM MQ connection refresh or invalidation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Current situation:
Spring boot application using `com.ibm.mq:mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` is receiving messages from IBM MQ and is working fine. Our IBM MQ server closes inactive connections after an hour and this throws exceptions at the client application `(IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN'))`. The client recovers correctly by starting a new connection but we want to prevent these errors by invalidating connections so we frequently get a new connection.

To prevent these inactive connections we would like the client application to make a new connection every 10 minutes for example when listening for messages. How would we configure these connections timeouts?

Comment: On the server side it is called AgedTimeout https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_jmsQueueConnectionFactory.html it seems.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring You can create a pooled connection factory

Comment: What does the `CURSHCNV` and `HBINT` show on the queue manager when you display channel status for the `SVRCONN` channel? What version of MQ jar files are you using?  What version is the queue manager?

Comment: Enabling the pool and setting the timeBetweenExpirationCheck doesn't prevent the issue. I don't have access to the server side for those parameters.

Comment: What version of MQ jar files are you using? What version is the queue manager?

Comment: ibm.mq.version 2.1.2 - it seems the properties are not being picked up

Comment: That is not a known MQ version,  check the `MANIFEST.MF` in the jar file.

Comment: Can you ask the MQ admin for what the `CURSHCNV` and `HBINT` show on the queue manager when you display channel status for the SVRCONN channel?

Comment: Is the queue manger closing the inactive session because of `DISCINT` or is this going through a firewall or load balancer which is dropping the connection after an hour?

Comment: Not sure, can't get a hold of the MQ admins. But that might be the one, do not think it is firewall related.

Comment: Hi @Jeff - What is the solution for this issue? I am also facing the same issue with SpringBoot JMS.

Comment: HI @Jeff, did you solve this issue? I'm with the same error here.

Comment: I can't say, it was with a previous client and I do not have the details with me anymore. Sorry.